# Is there any way to implement sleep/wait functionality in AFrame?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I have a AFrame webpage with some animation & background music. The animation starts as soon as page loads but music takes time to load. Is there a way like wait/sleep wrt the scene (or animation) so that my animation starts only after the music is loaded fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place your assets in the `a-assets` element so they block render until they load. You can find an example here: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/examples/showcase/anime-UI/index.html#L14

Answer (score 1):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.2.0/core/asset-management-system.html

Place assets (media elements such as `img`, `video`, `audio`, `a-asset-item`) into `<a-assets>` under `<a-scene>`:

```
<a-scene timeout="5000">
  <a-assets>
    <img id="myImg" crossorigin src="myimg.jpg">
    <video id="myVideo autoplay crossorigin src="myvideo.mp4"></video>
  </a-assets>

  <a-video src="#myVideo"></a-video>
</a-scene>
```

The scene will block initialization under assets are loaded. However, there is a *timeout* that defaults to 3 seconds where the scene will begin loading regardless. This is configurable with the `timeout` attribute as shown above.

If you want to absolutely block, you could set the `timeout` to a very high amount.

Using `<a-assets>` also gives browser caching and configuration of various media element attributes such as `crossorigin`, `autoplay`, `preload`.